# Different Action On Every Tap of Button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, show-hide, hidden

I am using a button to **show/hide** a view in SwiftUI. It is working fine when I first **tap** the button. Like this:

[image: my view]

The thing I want is when I **first tap** it, it has to show me my view. And when I **tap** it the **second** time, it has to again hide the view. And on *every tap* it has to *show/hide* the view respectively. In storyboard, this *scenario* is easy to handle but in *SwiftUI*, I don't know how to do this as I am new to SwiftUI.

My code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShowHideText: View {
    
    @State private var showName = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            
            Text("Users")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            if showName {
                name()
            } else {
                name()
                    .hidden()
            }
            
            
            Button("Show/Hide") {
                showName = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func name() -> some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("David")
            
            Text("Kate")
        }
        
    }
}

struct ShowHideText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShowHideText()
    }
}
```

And one more thing which I need to ask is in my code, if I use **.hidden()**, the view *hides* but the space of the view remains there. I don't know if there is a way that it hides the view and I also have the view's content as I have to do some work on its content too, or if it works fine if I **don't** use **.hidden()** and **name()** in **else** part and I can do some work with its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Button("Show/Hide") {
   showName = true
}
```

to

```
Button("Show/Hide") {
   showName.toggle()
}
```

Comment: it worked, and Did you understand the second part of the question if I hide some view, can I read its content?

Comment: Okay, and did I read that view's content too, as I need to use the name

Comment: I am talking about text label

Answer (score 0):

For second part of your question. Change

```
if showName {
    name()
} else {
    name()
        .hidden()
}
```

To

```
if showName {
    name()
}
```